# <nav> element transparent without any previous opacity/transparency adjustments HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, transparency, opacity

I have noticed my nav bar is transparent and I would like it to not be. I have no previous opacity/transparency set that would cause it to be inheriting the property. I would like to make my nav bar non transparent.

Here is the CSS:

```
nav {
margin: 20px auto; 
text-align: center;
} 
nav ul ul {
display: none;
} 
nav ul li:hover > ul {
display: block;
} 
nav ul {
font-size: 25px;
background: white;
padding: 0px;
border-radius: 10px;  
border-style: solid;
list-style: none;
position: relative;
display: inline-table;
} 
nav ul:after {
content: ""; 
clear: both; 
display: block;
} 
nav ul li {
float: left;
} 
nav ul li:hover {
background: black;
} 
nav ul li:hover a {
opacity: 1;
color: white;
} 
nav ul li a {
display: block; 
padding: 15px 20px;
color: black; 
text-decoration: none;
} 
nav ul ul {
background: #000000; 
border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
padding: 0;
position: absolute; 
top: 100%;
} 
nav ul ul li {
float: none; 
} 
nav ul ul li a {
padding: 15px 20px;
} 
nav ul ul li a:hover {
background: #2E2E2E;
border-radius: 10px;
}


#welcome_paragraph {
position: relative;
top: 50px;
width: 500px;
margin: auto;
}
```

Here is the corresponding HTML:

```
<nav>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Information</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Getting Started?</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Starter Kits</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Rebuildables</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Genesis</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Dripper</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Silica/Cotton</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Mods</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Mechanical</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Variable Voltage</a></li>
                    </ul>       
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Accessories</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
<p id="welcome_paragraph">
Welcome, blah blah (this text shows through the nav bar)<br />
</p>
```

Comment: upvote and mark the answer so it would be helpful to someine in the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Information</a>

            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Getting Started?</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">About Us</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Starter Kits</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Rebuildables</a>

            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Genesis</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Dripper</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Silica/Cotton</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Mods</a>

            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Mechanical</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Variable Voltage</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Accessories</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<p id="welcome_paragraph">Welcome, blah blah (this text shows through the nav bar)
    <br />
</p>
```

**CSS**

```
nav {
margin: 20px auto; 
text-align: center;
} 
nav ul ul {
display: none;
} 
nav ul li:hover > ul {
display: block;
} 
nav ul {
font-size: 25px;
background: white;
padding: 0px;
border-radius: 10px;  
border-style: solid;
list-style: none;
position: relative;
display: inline-table;
} 
nav ul:after {
content: ""; 
clear: both; 
display: block;
} 
nav ul li {
float: left;
} 
nav ul li:hover {
background: black;
    position:relative;
z-index:1;
} 
nav ul li:hover a {
color: white;
 position:relative;
 z-index:1;
} 
nav ul li a {
display: block; 
padding: 15px 20px;
color: black; 
text-decoration: none;
} 
nav ul ul {
background: #000000; 
border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
padding: 0;
position: absolute; 
top: 100%;
} 
nav ul ul li {
float: none; 
} 
nav ul ul li a {
padding: 15px 20px;
} 
nav ul ul li a:hover {
background: #2E2E2E;
border-radius: 10px;
}


#welcome_paragraph {
position: relative;
top: 50px;
width: 500px;
margin: auto;
    color:white;
}
body
{
    background-color:blue;
}
```

Updated **CSS** of yours

```
 nav ul li:hover {
background: black;
    position:relative;
z-index:1;
} 
nav ul li:hover a {
color: white;
 position:relative;
 z-index:1;
}
```

## [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sLC8s/24/)

Comment: Even in the fiddle it is still transparent to me. Maybe it's a browser thing?

Comment: Try to paste a large peice of text into the #welcome_message and it shows through

Comment: @AlekHurst you dont want the message to appear or it should appear??

Comment: I do not want the message to show through the drop-down portions of my nav bar. for example, if you have a large piece of text in the welcome_message and hover over the "information" tab, then hover over the "about us" or "contact" selection, the text shows through.

Comment: @AlekHurst i have updated you can check with the fiddle and do you want your menu to be in two columns if you want in single column you can check with this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sLC8s/12/)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried;

```
nav {
    background: white;
}
```

Elements are transparent unless you set a background on them or its inherited.

EDIT: If this doesn't help set up a fiddle for us jsfiddle.net.

Answer (score 0):

In your css

```
nav ul {
font-size: 25px;
background: white;
padding: 0px;
border-radius: 10px;  
border-style: solid;
list-style: none;
position: relative;
display: inline-table;
}
```

background is white.

If you change background to other colour may be your problem will go off. Hope it will help

Cheers !!

Comment: Thanks for the response, I have tried this and it wasn't successful